# Issue with mat datepicker in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I've never had this issue before with previous version yet I'm not sure if the version is the problem or I'm missing something completely obvious. When I set up an input with a mat datepicker and toggle I get the following error: A MatDatepicker can only be associated with a single input. With just one input and one datepicker. All the correct modules seem to be imported.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
    <mat-form-field style="margin-right: 20px;">
      <mat-label>Choose a start date</mat-label>
      <input matInput
             [matDatepicker]="startDate">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix
                             [for]="startDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #startDate></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

No models or form groups/controls added yet, just the plain old code that gives this issue. I've tried changing the "#startDate" on the mat-datepicker to "id='startDate'", which leads to no error being shown until the app is served again. The toggle won't work either then so that doesn't help much. Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue here because at this point I have no clue.

EDIT:

Here's a stackblitz of the code I use: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwh59k
Funny enough is that it doesn't give any issues whatsoever.

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz instance of your issue?

Comment: @Prince I've provided the stackblitz and it works like a charm there. For some reason I can't reproduce it there

Comment: Are you getting any error in your local instance?

Comment: Locally I get the error stated above: A MatDatepicker can only be associated with a single input.

`<input matInput
             [matDatepicker]="startDate">`

At the point where the datepicker is supposed to be connected with the input.

Comment: Can you please check if you are using  #startDate with any other input element? Need to see your code to tell the main reason behind it.

Comment: There was in fact another element with the same name. I made the id for the input and datepicker unique but the issue remains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211444/discussion-between-prince-and-sachey).

Comment: Please join this chat.